# Add Points from Added Source to Mapbox Label

Tags: label, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to take the data from an added layer and add it as the country-label on a stock map (in this case, Dark V 10).

Here is the code that allows me to add the data (**EatPlace**) from my added layer as a SEPARATE label (Works, but NOT what I want):

```
map.on('load', function() {

  map.addSource('CEVectorSource', { //The link to your tileset
      'type': 'vector',
      'url': 'mapbox://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });

  map.addLayer({
      "id": "CountriesEatenNames",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "CEVectorSource",
      "source-layer": "CEVectorsTileset",
      "filter": ["all",["match", ["geometry-type"], ["Point"], true, false]],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": ['format',
        ['upcase', ['get', 'EatPlace']], { 'font-scale': .8 },
        '\n', {},
        ['get', 'EatDate'], { 'font-scale': .6 }],
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        //"text-allow-overlap": true,
        "text-variable-anchor": ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color" : 'rgb(255, 221, 153)' // Text Color
      }
    });
});
```

Here is the code that lets me modify the labels I want to modify:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field',
  ['get', 'name_en'])
```

Here is what has NOT worked:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field',
  ['get', 'EatPlace'])
```

I have no luck combining these concepts. Any help would be divine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a country tileset of points, a places tileset of points, and you want to display for each country point a piece of text deriving from the places tileset.

That isn't going to work. How would Mapbox-GL-JS know which country point to associate with a given place point? You will need to find some way to combine them into one layer first.

Comment: The country tileset is the stock map, so yes I have a country tileset of points. The places tileset contains country names which match those in the country tileset. Therefor Mapbox should be able to run a formula that says "if country names match, add the data in the places tileset to the label in the countries tileset."  I don't know how to construct that though.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean by "should be able to". Mapbox-GL-JS doesn't support any kind of joining between separate layers.

Comment: Could one not implement a loop of some sort to achieve it?